# HttpUrlConnection hangs out on POST request

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I am working on custom `gradle` plugin which trigger API `POST` call. There is no many option for networking from `gradle` and `UrlConnection` looks as a best tool. I am able to trigger GET API call, but can not do it for POST.

Here is my client code from gradle plugin:

```
interface SwapTestPluginExtension {
    val backEndEndpoint: Property<String>
}

class SwapTestPlugin: Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(target: Project) {

        val extension = target.extensions.create("swapTest", SwapTestPluginExtension::class.java)
        target.task("prepareTestEnvironment") {
            doLast {
                try {
                    println("[start] ${SwapTestPlugin::class.simpleName}")
                    executePostApiCall(extension)
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    println("Something whent wrong in ${SwapTestPlugin::class.simpleName} with exception ${ex}")
                } finally {
                    println("[end] ${SwapTestPlugin::class.simpleName}")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun executePostApiCall(extension: SwapTestPluginExtension) {
        val credentials = "{\"name\": \"\", \"pwd\" : \"\"}"
        val req = URL("${extension.backEndEndpoint.get()}/test/environment").openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        req.setRequestMethod("POST")
        req.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
        req.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
        req.setDoOutput(true)
        println("[swap-test-plugin] prepare to call API")
        req.getOutputStream().write(JsonOutput.toJson(credentials).toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)/*.getBytes("UTF-8")*/)
        req.outputStream.flush()
        println("[swap-test-plugin] API has been called, going to read results")
        val br = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(req.inputStream, Charsets.UTF_8.name()))
        val response = StringBuilder()
        var responseLine: String? = null
        while (br.readLine().also { responseLine = it } != null) {
            response.append(responseLine!!.trim { it <= ' ' })
        }
        println("[swap-test-plugin] prepare to parse result")
        val json = JsonSlurper().parseText(response.toString())
        println("[json] ${json}")
    }

}
```

Here is stubs for API methods on the backend:

```
controllers/test.js

const config = require('config');
const network = require('../utils/network')
const logger = require('../utils/logger')

exports.setEnvironment = async function(req, res) { 
    logger.log("[start] /test/environment call");
    let result
    if (config.isProduction) {
        result = network.getErrorMsg(501, "This method is only supported for non-production mode for test purposes.")
    } else {
        // TODO clean up database if it is a debug mode
        result = network.getMsg(200, JSON.stringify({"msg" : "just a stub"}));
    }
    logger.log(`[end] response ${JSON.stringify(result)}`)
    network.send(req, res, result);
}

routes/index.js
...
router.post('/api/v1/test/environment', tests.setEnvironment);
...
```

Wireshark shows an POST request happens, but there is not activity on the server - it looks like it never reaches. The similar GET request works fine. [Here is a source code](https://github.com/Gelassen/swap/tree/main/server) of the backend in case you would like to copy-paste this block of code and reproduce.

```
1589    960.149964545   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   HTTP/JSON   100 POST /api/v1/test/environment HTTP/1.1 , JavaScript Object Notation (application/json)
1590    960.149967554   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP 66  3100 → 50170 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=262 Win=65280 Len=0 TSval=3277455079 TSecr=3277455079
```

Do you notice cause of this issue?

Comment: I guess the issue here is that you write data to the output stream of the connection, but you do not close the output stream, so your POST request is not being finalized

Comment: Not, it is not an issue. To confirm end of writing ```flush()``` call is used, server should receive data, but it is not happened.